# Доработка ввода номера через input: авто-перестановка курсора

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, input

Есть `input` в который пользователь вводит номер телефона:

```
<input autofocus="autofocus" type="tel"  name="phone" id="phone_number"/>
```

Используется  jQuery Masked Input Plugin Version: 1.4.1

У `input` есть маска `+7(___)___-__-__`

```
if (!$.browser.msie && !parseInt($.browser.version)<7) 
    {$('#phone_number').mask("+7(999)999-99-99");}
```

Если пользователь передвинул курсор в середину маски, то ему сложно ввести номер телефона (особенно если он смотрит сайт на смартфоне).

Например, он случайно передвинул курсор `+7(___)___-КУРСОР __-__`  Тогда, когда он начнет вводить номер, получится ввести только 4 цифры. `+7(___)___-98-76`. А далее ввести нельзя.

Есть две разные идеи:

1. Как-то запретить ставить курсор так, что бы слева от курсора были пустые (незаполненные) символы. Тогда в примере выше: Если пользователь хочет поставить курсор в центре `+7(___)___-КУРСОР __-__`   то он автоматический передвигается влево:  `+7(КУРСОР ___)___- __-__`
2. Как-то реализовать: Если пользователь поставил курсор в центр `+7(___)___-КУРСОР __-__` и начал вводить номер телефона, то  ввод происходит так:

```html
+7(___)___-КУРСОР __-__  
+7(___)___-9_-__     
+7(___)___-98-__   
+7(___)___-98-7_   
+7(___)___-98-76
+7(___)__9-87-65
+7(___)_98-76-54
+7(___)987-65-43
+7(__9)876-54-32
+7(_98)765-43-21
+7(987)654-32-10
```

Как реализовать эти варианты?

Comment: Кажется, первый вариант лучше!

Comment: Я готов на оба варианта. Но не понимаю как их реализовать.

Comment: Пример того, как можно двигать курсор https://jsfiddle.net/fwm2hdcx/1/

Answer (score 1):

jQuery, плагины, "допиливание" плагинов... Нативом работы на час:

```js
document.querySelectorAll('input.phone').forEach(function(item) {
  item.addEventListener('input', function() {
    fCurPosEnd(this);
  });
  item.addEventListener('click', function() {
    fCurPosEnd(this);
  });
  item.addEventListener('keyup', function() {
    fCurPosEnd(this);
  });
  fCurPosEnd(item);
});

function fCurPosEnd(el) {
  let sVal = el.value.replace(/\D+/gi, '').slice(1);
  sVal = sVal + '__________'.slice(sVal.length);
  let sNumb = sVal.match(/(.{3})(.{3})(.{2})(.{2})/);
  el.value = '+7(' + sNumb[1] + ')' + sNumb[2] + '-' + sNumb[3] + '-' + sNumb[4];
  el.focus();
  el.selectionStart = el.selectionEnd = (el.value.search(/[)-]*_/gi) < 0) ?
    el.value.length :
    el.value.search(/[)-]*_/gi);
}
```

```css
input.phone:invalid { background: #fdd; } input.phone:valid { background: #cfc; }
```

```html
<input class="phone" type="text" pattern="[^_]*">
```

*PS Не проверял на кроссбраузерность (Win7+Chrome70 - "на ура!")*

Comment: Невозможно поставить курсор в произвольное место, если часть данных введена.

Comment: @StepanKasyanenko что значит в "произвольное место"? Номер справа налево диктуют и записывают что ли? В примере всё логично - начал набирать, прервался, продолжил с места, где остановился. Если ставить в произвольное место, то вероятность ошибиться, поставив курсор "не туда", намного выше, чем набирать цифры по порядку.

Comment: Начал набирать, набрал 8 цифр. Увидел, что ошибся в 3 цифре. А курсор поставить и изменить нельзя. Придется все стирать, потом заново набирать. Не очень удобный UX.

Comment: @StepanKasyanenko повторный ввод заставит более внимательно отнестись к набору. А за "удобствами" можно и не заметить, что ошибся ещё и в пятой цифре)) Ждём вашего решения сего вопроса ;-)

Comment: Смешно, конечно. Запретим изменять текст в инпуте, что бы пользователь внимательно вводил. Желаю вам, что бы на СО сделали такой инпут при ответе - менять нельзя, только стирать и заново вводить. Это повысит качество ответов! Можете внести как предложение на MSE)))

Answer (score 0):

Решил немного по иному. Если пользователь не ввел еще ни одной цифры, то курсор намертво прибит к первой позиции.Если же уже успели что-то ввести, то курсор можно передвинуть, что  бы что-то отредактировать.

```html
        $('#phone_number').click(function(){
            if ($('#phone_number').val() == "+7(___)___-__-__")
                {$(this)[0].selectionStart = 3; $(this)[0].selectionEnd = 3;}
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

Это делается очень просто, смотри, после +7 у тебя появляется _____. И из-за нее курсор ставится в конце. Мы просто уберем нижнее подчеркивание и курсор всегда будет попадать после +7 и к тому же, с возможностью редактировать номер без стирания :) То есть просто добавь через запятую плейсхолдер с кавычками и закрывающимися тегами. Такое решение применяется для интеграции сервиса по Смс рассылкам, т.к. требуются номера в формате +7хххххх

```
jQuery(function($){
   $("#pop_phone").mask("+7(999) 999-9999", {placeholder: "" });
});
```

Comment: В текущем виде ваш ответ непонятен. Пожалуйста, нажмите [edit] под сообщением, чтобы добавить больше подробностей, которые помогут другим понять, как он отвечает на заданный вопрос. Вы можете найти больше информации о том, как писать хорошие ответы в [Справке](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Это решение ставит курсор на тот момент, где пользователь закончил вводить номер

```
$.fn.setCursorPosition = function(pos) {
  if ($(this).get(0).setSelectionRange) {
    $(this).get(0).setSelectionRange(pos, pos);
  } else if ($(this).get(0).createTextRange) {
    var range = $(this).get(0).createTextRange();
    range.collapse(true);
    range.moveEnd('character', pos);
    range.moveStart('character', pos);
    range.select();
  }
};
function rightPos(phone) {
  for (var i = 0; i < phone.length; i++) {
    if(phone.charAt(i) == "_") {
      console.log(phone.charAt(i));
      return i
    }
  }
  return phone.length - 1
}
$("input[name=phone]").click(function(){
  let phone = $(this).val()
  $(this).setCursorPosition(rightPos(phone));
}).mask("+7 (999) 999-9999", {autoclear: false});
```