# Периодические проблемы с вводом по маске MaskedInput

Tags: javascript, jquery

Использую на сайте [моцная.бел](https://%D0%BC%D0%BE%D1%86%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F.%D0%B1%D0%B5%D0%BB) для ввода телефона, библиотеку maskedinput-1.4.1.js

На десктопе все работает  корректно, а на некоторых мобильных устройствах и на android и на IOS иногда происходят глюки такого рода:

- начинаешь вводить цифры в начале, - а они вводятся в конце;
- либо при вводе курсор перепрыгивает в самое начало перед плюсом и потом просто автозаменой все перекрывается
- иногда говорят что вообще не получается что-либо ввести

Может кто-нибудь уже сталкивался с проблемами такого рода и знает как их решить?

Или может есть достойная замена maskedinput?

Comment: похожая тема уже поднималась. Может поможет с решением - https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/902456/265406

Comment: много тестировал и заметил, что такая проблема появляется на телефонах xiaomi именно в Mi браузере... может как-то можно обойти его?

Comment: UModeL, - то что вы скинули, то это немного не тот вариант

Comment: как вариант можно использовать вот такие аналоги: https://nosir.github.io/cleave.js/ или http://igorescobar.github.io/jQuery-Mask-Plugin/