# Как запретить удаление определенной части в input?

Tags: javascript

В input phone через кнопку вставляются различные коды стран. Эту часть нельзя указать вручную
Как можно запретить удаление этого кода? Например могут быть такие коды "+7_" или "+987_"
*без нагромождения в верстке скрытых заглушек для имитации начала input, есть только 1 голый input.

Регулярное выражение почему-то  не срабатывает.

```js
 document.querySelector('#phone').addEventListener('keydown', valid);
 document.querySelector('#phone2').addEventListener('keydown', valid);
 
 
 function valid(event) {
  if (this.value === /^\+\d+\s/ && event.key === 'Backspace') { 
   event.preventDefault() 
  }
 }
```

```html
<input type="text" id="phone" value="+7 ">
<input type="text" id="phone2" value="+987 ">
```

Comment: а если по ошибке ввели лишнюю цифру в код +9875 - теперь 5 никогда не убрать

Comment: первая часть кода вставляется только кнопкой выбор страны. код нельзя указать вручную. Код в конце содержит пробел +XXX_

Comment: так и держите его в другом инпуте - просто и кучу проблем решите

Comment: можете даже флаг показывать, как часто делают

Comment: Сайт на конструкторе. Можно, конечно, наваять createElement.. Но лучше ограничиться 1 input =) поэтому возник спортивный интерес

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Всё у Вас срабатывает, если быть внимательнее. Но, подход всё равно неверный.

```js
document.querySelector('#phone').addEventListener('keydown', valid);
document.querySelector('#phone2').addEventListener('keydown', valid);

function valid(event) {
  if (/^\+\d+ $/.test(this.value) && event.key === 'Backspace') {
    event.preventDefault();
  }
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="phone" value="+7 ">
<input type="text" id="phone2" value="+987 ">
```

Comment: Уточните, пожалуйста, почему неверный? Да, лучше заглушку сделать, но сайт на конструкторе, там только 1 статический input =) Спасибо за ответ!

Comment: @VanilJS: если каким-либо образом вставить любой символ в начало поля, то всё - логика не работает.

Comment: @VanilJS: для более сложных проверок, кода должно быть больше) А, если есть возможность использовать _javascript_, то возможностей куча (например, динамически добавлять атрибуты и тд.). Может заинтересует или натолкнёт на мысль - https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/902514/265406

Comment: Можно еще уточнить, как разрешить удаление следующих цифр? Регулярка на отсутствие следующих символов не помогает( /^\+\d+\s[^.]/

Comment: @VanilJS: подправил.

Comment: Спасибо!! только начал учить регулярки =) незаменимая вещь.

Comment: @UModeL Поздравляю с первой 10k в репе!!!